# How to add custom html in a genesis theme between entry-meta and entry-content

Tags: wordpress, genesis

I want to know how can I add a custom html code in a genesis template between entry-meta and entry-content in a post page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the genesis code that close the header

```
add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_entry_header_markup_close', 15 );
/**
 * Echo the closing structural markup for the entry header.
 *
 * @since 2.0.0
 */
function genesis_entry_header_markup_close() {
    echo '</header>';
}
```

The priority is 15 and that the reason that priority for the my code has to be greater

```
add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'add_stuff_after_title', 100 );
function add_stuff_after_title() {
    if(is_singular('post')) {
        _e("<span>This is before the ending header tag.</span>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `genesis_entry_header` action. This allows you to inject content into the end of the header.

```
add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'add_stuff_after_title', 12 );
function add_stuff_after_title() {
    if(is_singular('post')) {
        _e("<span>This is before the ending header tag.</span>");
    }
}
```

Comment: I change the $priority to 100 and the code works perfect